# How do you get top to show wall clock time?

Tags: top

Is there a way to configure `top` to show wall clock time rather than CPU time? I'm sure CPU time is useful in some contexts, but in mine I want to know how long the process has been running since I started it per my watch. I currently use top to show me CPU utilization and other process metrics, then switch to `ps -o etime= -p <pid>` to see the wall clock time. It would be convenient if I could just use `top` for both of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top` doesn't have this feature.

Please file a feature request or better yet submit a patch here: https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps

Alternatively you could use `htop` which has `STARTTIME`: *Time the process was started*.